# wordpress tags as twitter sharer URL hastags

Tags: wordpress, twitter, tags

I want to share a wordpress post on twitter. I'm using this :

```
     <a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink() ?>&text=<?php the_title() ?>&via=<?php the_author() ?>&hashtags=<?php the_tags('', '') ?>" ></a>
```

My problem is that `the_tags()` prints the tags inside the `<a>` tag !
I know that hashtags should be separated with Comma on URL.
so how can I use `the_tags('', '')` ( which separates the tags with comma as the hashtag needs to be ) for twitter hashtags ?

I appreciate solutions without plugin
thanks

Answer (score 1):

you could use: get_the_tags() instead of the_tags()

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags

```
     $posttags = get_the_tags();
     $twitter_tags="";
     if ($posttags) {
      foreach($posttags as $tag) {
          $twitter_tags.=$tag->name.',';
      }
     }

     echo $twitter_tags; // inside twitter link
```